# Integer/Float Class in java/C#

Tags: java, c#

I have this code in java:

```
private String updateTargetValue() {
    Integer i, i1;
    Float f, f1;
    ...
    f1 = new Float(f.floatValue() *  i.intValue() );
    i1 = new Integer(f1.intValue());
    ...

 }
```

To conver this code to C#, I need to Find an equivalent C# class for Integer and Float but there is no equivalent class for them. So, I tried to use Pasrse:

```
private String updateTargetValue() {
        int i, i1;
        float f, f1;
        ...

        f1 = float.Parse((float)f * (int)i);
        i1 = Convert.ToInt32((int)f1);
        ...

     }
```

i1 looks correct but I get eroor in in f1. Does anyone have an idea how do I solve it?

Error is in ( (float)f * (int)i):

> The best overloaded method take match for parse..

.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `i.intValue()` to just `i`.  Also, don't change the question.  Look at the API for the methods you're using...you're using them wrong.

Comment: Also, `f` and `f1` should be of type `float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change this:

```
f1 = float.Parse((float)f * (int)i);
i1 = Convert.ToInt32((int)f1);
```

To:

```
f1 = f * ((float)i);
i1 = ((int)f1);
```

Then later you could convert it to a string as so:

```
string sf1 = f1.ToString();
string si1 = i1.ToString();
```

I would recommend looking at the API for each method you are using because you are using the methods incorrectly.  Also, the error messages tell you what is wrong.  Try your best to understand them.

Comment: Great...How do I convert this: int kHi = (i.intValue()  & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;

Comment: @user3651666 Did you try `int kHi = (i & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16`  ? `intValue()` method doesn't exist in C# for `int` variables...

Comment: @user3651666 `0xFFFF0000` is a `long`.  You can't convert it to an `int`.  Try  `long kHi = (i & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;`

Comment: yes you are right...now, i do not get error but why using int kHi was correct in Java code?!

Comment: @user3651666 They are two different languages that work differently.  They have different rules, classes, etc.

Answer (score 6):

C# doesn't have the same dual `float`/`Float` as Java (nor for `int` or any other built in 'primitive' as they're known in Java.)

So you can just use the number directly

For example, this is valid C#:

```
string s = 123.ToString();
```

You have this in your code:

```
Convert.ToInt32((int)f1);
```

The first step is a cast:

```
(int)f1
```

This casts the float to an int. The result of that expression is an int.

It's not invalid to call `Convert.ToInt32` on an int, but it doesn't do anything and is just wasteful. If you know the conversion is safe, just do the cast. However if the inbound value could be something else (perhaps a string) then calling `Convert.ToInt32` may be the better option.

---

In short, this code in Java:

```
Integer i, i1;
Float f, f1;
...
f1 = new Float(f.floatValue() *  i.intValue() );
i1 = new Integer(f1.intValue());
```

should be, in C#:

```
int i, i1;
float f, f1;
...
f1 = f * i;
i1 = (int)f1; // cast required for narrowing conversion
```

Comment: I changed it to :  f1 = float.Parse(f * i) but still I get error!

Comment: `float.Parse` expects a `string`, but the result of `f * i` is already a `float`. So try only having `f1 = f * i;`.

Comment: This guy is unbelievable

Comment: Thanks a lot..please let me know why using just 'i' does not work in this case: int kHi = (i.intValue() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16

Answer (score 2):

Java Integer and Float are nullable, so I think a more accurate conversion would be:

```
int? i, i1;
float? f, f1;

f1 = new float?((float)f * (int)i);
i1 = new int?((int)f1);
```